# Saving/updating a model with nested attributes and single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, single-table-inheritance

I have a model, `ModelRun`, that accepts nested attributes for another model, `ParameterValue`. (`ModelRun has_many :parameter_values`.) However, `ParameterValue` also employs single-table inheritance to save two subclasses: `NumericParameter` and `FileParameter`. `FileParameter` uses [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) to store a file.

The problem is that in `ModelRunController` when saving or updating a `ModelRun`, by default, `@model_run.save` or `@model_run.update_attributes` does not identify the type of `ParameterValue` attributes - it just tries to store them as `ParameterValue`. This works for `NumericParameter` values, but it raises an exception for `FileParameters` because the [CarrierWave uploader doesn't get mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8310758/81554) to handle the file upload so ActiveRecord fails when trying to serialize the file to the database.

What's the cleanest way to handle this problem? The only solution that occurred to me was to manually populate the `@model_run.parameter_values` collection in the controller's `create` and `update` methods, since I can tell which type each `ParameterValue` should be and create the correct objects one by one. However, this seems like reimplementing a lot of Rails magic since I can't just use `ModelRun.new(params[:model_run])` or `@model_run.update_attributes` anymore - seems like it throws away much of the advantage of using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the first place. Is there a better way, a Rails Way™?

Relevant parts of each model are copied below.

#### model_run.rb

```
class ModelRun < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parameter_values, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parameter_values, allow_destroy: true

  attr_accessible :name, 
                  :description, 
                  :geometry_description, 
                  :run_date, 
                  :run_date_as_string, 
                  :parameter_values_attributes
end
```

#### parameter_value.rb

```
class ParameterValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model_run

  attr_accessible :type,
                  :parameter_id, 
                  :description, 
                  :numeric_value,
                  :model_run_id,
                  :parameter_file
end
```

#### numeric_parameter.rb

```
class NumericParameter < ParameterValue
  attr_accessible :numeric_value
end
```

#### file_parameter.rb

```
class FileParameter < ParameterValue
  mount_uploader :parameter_file, ParameterFileUploader

  attr_accessible :parameter_file
end
```

#### parameter_file_uploader.rb

```
class ParameterFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads/cache/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand you well, you are trying to find convinient way of instantiating right subclass in STI hierarchy by passing :type?. If you don't need to change the type later, you can just add this hack to your ParameterValue class

```
class ParameterValue < ActiveRecord::Base
    class << self
      def new_with_cast(*attributes, &block)
        if (h = attributes.first).is_a?(Hash) && !h.nil? && (type = h[:type] || h['type']) && type.length > 0 && (klass = type.constantize) != self
          raise "wtF hax!!"  unless klass <= self
          return klass.new(*attributes, &block)
        end

        new_without_cast(*attributes, &block)
      end
      alias_method_chain :new, :cast

    end
  end
```

After this, passing right type will cause right ParameterValue instatntiating, including uploaders, validation etc.

Comment: Brilliant - way better than the hack I came up with, and taught me about metaclasses. Thanks!